# Chart.js time tracker

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, chart.js

i am trying to build simple time tracker with chart.js.

It will be grouped by date. I.e 11.12, 12.12, 13.12.... (day .
month)

From my `js` file i call `ajax` and `php` server to return me `json`.

```
datasert: {
...
     data: [12, 5, 12, 53] // time in minutes
.....
}
```

In this examle i use one result, it will be more that one. I.e 5 per page.

Using `bar` type chart i got 4 chart instead one.

So my questions is:
is it posible to get one bar chart from example above like in image example and how? (Spent 5h trying)

And is it posible to join start date? I.e 10.12 startet at 9am, 11.12 startet at 9:25am....

[image: Time tracker]
<sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/c99a02ccad26067467b6b8cd39cf17f6.png))</sub>

Comment: "It will be grouped by date. I.e 11.12, 12.12, 13.12" what is 13.12? is that `day.month`?

Comment: Yes  sorry i will update now